# Vue component only updates after mouse hover

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a list of objects in the state, I iterate over them in a v-for, populating a list of components, however the component only updates its data once I hover over them with the mouse.

```
<goal
  v-for="goal in this.$store.state.goals"
  :key="goal.project + goal.description"
  v-bind:goal="goal"
/>
```

[image: The problem]

The component code is [here](https://github.com/rzfzr/toboard/blob/main/src/components/Goal.vue)

Comment: going to take a wild guess and say its `v-hover`

Comment: @MichaelMano took it out, now it stays with the default values, hovering does not update

Comment: stange thing, all information is present in the prop at created

Comment: try update the values of goal with `Vue.set()`. please add the relevant store code as well (it is better to add it to the question instead of link to github)